# How to force jquery $.when(...) to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred

```
$.when(a1, ...).fail(function() { alert('fail'); });
```

Is there a value for a1 that would force the deferred object to fail, while not doing any malformed ajax calls within the object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a [rejected](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.reject/) [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/):

```
$.when($.Deferred().reject()).fail(function() {
    alert("fail");
});
```

You can test it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V23zt/).

Comment: Thanks, can you enhance your answer by giving an example with ajax function passed in $.when and when ajax function fails. (How to call deffered object and alert user)

Comment: @Dave, I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. If the promise returned by a call to `$.ajax()` is passed to `$.when()` and the request fails, the `fail` handler will be called in the same way as here.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @Frédéric Hamidi, if you have a "async" function which is not already "promisized" then it will often have a success and failure callback.

Then you do something like:

```
// @returns {promise} a promise
function callAsync(args){
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  ApiNotReturningPromise.ajax(args, function success(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
    // if you wish to always fail: o.O
    // deferred.reject(data);
  }, function fail(error) {
    deferred.reject(error);
  });

  return deferred.promise();
}
```

Again, you can just fail in both cases here if you wish to, although that seems to make little sense to me, by

But, if it already is a Promise, (and AFAIK promise-like is enough for jQuery) then you can just reuse that promise.